# Responsive text using news show pro gk5

Tags: html, css, joomla

Using the module News Show Pro GK5 in Joomla 3, I did the following setup:

Amount of columns 1, amount of rows 1.
Image: float left,
Header: float right,
Text: float right

The image is set to responsive, wrap content and image auto-scale on.

The content appears as it should: the image on the left and the title and text next to it, on the right. Un fortunatelly, when the browser is resized to a smaller size, the title and text shrinks keeping its position to the right. I would like the title and text to move bellow the image when the browser width is small enough.

Any ideas to get this responsive behaviour on News Show Pro GK5?

Answer (score 1):

To responsive News Show Pro GK4/5, you can overide your code, some things must be change:
img {
max-width:100%}

Change from style="width:50%;" to style="width:300px;"